# Determining if a Part of a string is in a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, set

Given the input

```
Guess='1 5K'
```

and a list

```
playable=['AC','QS','5S','5K','KC']
```

How would I go about determining if the '5K' part of Guess is in playable? Also, if it is in playable, how would I go about determining if the item 1 spot to the left of it has either a '5' or a 'K' in it. So playable would become

```
playable=['AC','QS','5K','KC']
```

With '5K' replacing '5S'. 
So far I have

```
def oneC(Guess):
    split_em=Guess.split() ##splits at space
    card_guess=split_em[1] ##gets the '5K' part of string
    if card_guess is in playable:
                                          ##Confusion Area
        index1=playable.index(card_guess) ##Finds index of '5K'
        index_delete= del playable[index1-1] ##Deletes item to the left of '5K'
```

My problem right now is i'm not sure how to determine if '5' or 'K' is in the item one spot to the left. Is there a way to turn '5K' into a set of ('5','K') and then turn the element one spot to the left to ('5','S') and run intersection on them? I wrote this on my phone because my internet is down at my house so sorry for any confusion or misspellings. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to accomplish.  Your goal seems to be to remove the item left of the one specified by `Guess`; correct?  And it looks like the order in this spec is important, so building sets won't make sense.  It would mean that '5K' is handled like 'K5'.  Do you want that?  (Your code looks like poker card stuff.)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the characters in the item to the left and see if '5' or 'K' is in there:

```
index1 = playable.index(card_guess)
if any(c in playable[index1 - 1] for c in card_guess):
    del playable[index1]
```

Note that the above code does not check for the case where `index1 == 0` so you'd have to define what happens when the guessed card is the first card in the list.

So to answer your question: `for c in card_guess` iterates over the characters in `"5K"` (which are `'5'` and `'K'` and it then checks if any of those are in `playable[index1 - 1]`, which is the item to the left of `"5K"`).